# Nested list looping and wanting to make each loop have index 0 and 1

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops, enumerate

**List**

```
list_a = [[1, 2],[3, 4], [5, 6]]

for index, item in enumerate(list_a):
# do something
```

**Description of task required**

My question is, how would I write this loop if I wanted to retrieve each seperate list within list_a as index 0 and 1. At the moment [1, 2] is index 0, [3, 4] is index 1 etc. But what I am chasing is the following:

[1, 2] would have 1 as index 0 and 2 as index 1, then I would perform some task and then move onto the following where [3, 4] would have 3 as index 0 and 4 as index 1 and perform the same task as before. Any help would be awesome! :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you already have the indexing you need. Try `print(list_a[0][0]), list_a[0][1]))`. Just nest another loop through `item` in the loop you already have

Comment: You already have what you need in variable `item` inside loop *(if I've understood you)*

Comment: why do you need indexes - most of the times the values are fare more important... and you can just `for item in listvar:` over them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
for small_list in list_a:
    for index, item in enumerate(small_list):
        print index, item
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not sure what you mean. This would have 1 as index 0, 2 as index 1, 3 as index 0, and 4 as index 1 just as the op asked

Comment: My original comment was stupid. I didn't read carefully. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need the enumerate for this:

```
list_a = [[1, 2],[3, 4], [5, 6]]

for item in list_a:
    print(item[0], item[1])
```